# The receiver sends correct but too much information to the keyboard with STM32 nRF24

Tags: stm32, usb-device, keyboard, nrf24l01, keypad

I have a problem with keyboard hid. I did remote control with STM32 transceiver nRF24. My problems that receiver true receiving incoming data but too much text. Problems that:

```c
if (keyRead[1] == 169) {

    keyboardhid.KEYCODE1 = 0x20; //3
    USBD_CUSTOM_HID_SendReport(&hUsbDeviceFS, &keyboardhid, sizeof (keyboardhid));

    HAL_Delay(gecikme); //200

    keyboardhid.KEYCODE1 = 0x00;
    USBD_CUSTOM_HID_SendReport(&hUsbDeviceFS, &keyboardhid, sizeof (keyboardhid));

    HAL_Delay(gecikme); //200

    // keyboardhid.MODIFIER = 0x02;  // left shift pressed
    keyboardhid.KEYCODE2 = 0x0B; // H harfi
    USBD_CUSTOM_HID_SendReport(&hUsbDeviceFS, &keyboardhid, sizeof (keyboardhid));

    HAL_Delay(gecikme); //200

    keyboardhid.KEYCODE2 = 0x00;
    USBD_CUSTOM_HID_SendReport(&hUsbDeviceFS, &keyboardhid, sizeof (keyboardhid));

    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(yesil_GPIO_Port, yesil_Pin, 1);
    HAL_Delay(250);
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(yesil_GPIO_Port, yesil_Pin, 0);
}
```

For example:
If sender that data 169 keyboard must be write "3h" but sometimes "3hh" sometimes "3h3" write.
Where is the problem?

Comment: What is the reason that you use _keyboardhid.KEYCODE**1**_ to send a '3', and _keyboardhid.KEYCODE**2**_ to send an 'h'?

Comment: How are you debouncing your keyboard inputs? What does HAL_Delay(250) do?

Comment: I'm guessing that the snippet of code you've posted is enclosed in a `for` or `while` loop or something like that in your program. After you're processing the `keyRead` array here, do you clear its contents before the loop loops back around?

Comment: absolutely my choice, just a array @Velvel

Comment: I changed the keyboard inputs, I change the output according to the information I want. I also tried 250 ms but after a while it repeated again. @winny

Comment: how can ı do? can u examples for me @brhans

Comment: That didn't answer my question, _how_ do you debounce the keyboard?

Comment: @winny sorry, what did u mean, can u explain please?

Comment: Yes, for any key press in digital systems you need debouncing, analog in the button itself, electrical by a low pass filter or as done today in 99.99 % of cases, digital in code. How are you doing it?

Comment: I used a 4x4 keypad. when a key is pressed, the information I assigned is sent. its a basic 4x4 keypad.